# Successful Message Push To StockTwits, Chart Not Showing

Tags: stocktwits

I can successfully post a message. However when I try with a chart, I get back a success code (200) with the following URL's in the response:

http://charts.stocktwits.com/production/large_.png
http://charts.stocktwits.com/production/small_.png

When I Try to view the message in StockTwits, I get image not found
http://stks.co/p2kuK

I assume there should be some code after large_ and small_; hence the image not found.

Since no errors came back in JSON Response, I assume everything worked OK.

Link to Chart I'm uploading with API:
http://tradescribe.com/images/performance_graphs/AStrakaus-3GTakeover-5day.png

Any ideas?

The message appears in StockTwits without the Chart so API call looks to be correct

Code

```
$postdata = array(
    'access_token' => <TOKEN>,
    'body' => <MESSAGE INFORMATION>,
    'chart' => <FULLY QUALIFIED URL TO IMAGE>
);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/messages/create.json',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postdata
));
```

Comment: are you doing this programmatically or through a webform, or?

Comment: please post some code :-)

Comment: sorry I can't seem to format the code right for the comments section..I've updated the question

Comment: Any luck here? I'm seeing the exact same behavior with the chart URLs not appearing correctly in the JSON response, but the message itself going through correctly. It seems to work correctly for some accounts but not others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have fixed an issue on our end that was causing this problem and shouldn't be happening anymore.